# ¿Como vinculo varias funciones a un mismo boton de tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Lo que quiero hacer es que al presionar el botón theme se ponga un grupo de colores y al volverlo a  presionar otro diferente, ya tengo que si lo toco una vez cambia, pero nada mas.

````
ventana.geometry("451x700")
ventana.title("Calculadora")
def  verde():
    ventana.config(bg='green')
def azul():
    ventana.config(bg='#0FA9FE')

#variables para alto y ancho de los botones
alto=3
ancho=11


#Todos los  botones
Theme=Button(ventana, text='Theme', width=ancho, height=alto, command=azul)```

*No están todos los botones para no alargar*
````

Comment: Puedes usar una clase que tenga de atributo un booleano que indique si el tema está encendido. Puedes hacer lo mismo con una variable global. Puedes cambiar la función que llama el botón dentro de la función que llamó. Que intentaste hasta ahora para lograrlo?

Comment: Hasta ahora  probé usar una función lambda en el  command y así poner las dos  variables, pero eso lo que hizo fue fusionar las  dos funciones, no una  y luego al darle otra vez click otra

Comment: @EmilioCostaguta, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Lo que buscas se llaman botones tipo Toggle o de auto retención, su funcionamiento en general es, se oprime y hace una función y se oprime una segunda vez y hace otra función, el ejemplo clásico sería un botón de encendido y apagado.

Para hacerlo tienes que crear una variable global que te permita "guardar" el estado del botón y al ejecutar la función comparar esa variable global para ver qué función realizar.

Si utilizas el argumento `command` como ya lo descubriste vas a ejecutar las dos funciones al mismo tiempo

Supongamos que queremos hacer un botón de encendido/apagado, para eso vamos a crear una variable global

```
is_on = True
```

Luego en la función del botón comparamos el estado de `is_on` y las acciones a ejecutar:

```
# Función para el botón
def switch():
    # Usamos la variable global para saber el estado actual del botón
    global is_on
    
    # Determina si el botón está encendido o apagado
    if is_on:
        on_button.config(text = off)
        my_label.config(text = "El estatus del botón es OFF",
                        fg = "red")
        is_on = False
    else:
        on_button.config(text = on)
        my_label.config(text = "El estatus del botón es ON", fg = "green")
        is_on = True
```

En este ejemplo sencillo el botón ejecuta únicamente 2 tareas, si quisieras que ejecutara más tendrías que crear un entero y cambiarlo cada vez que se oprima el botón, pero también deberías cuidar los límites del rango de la variable global para evitar que tengas un botón que deba hacer digamos 3 acciones y que por alguna razón termine con el valor igual a 9 por ejemplo, porque entonces ya ninguna acción se realizaría...

Ejemplo completo:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Botón On/Off')
root.geometry("600x300")

# Variable global para saber si el estado del botón es ON/OFF
is_on = True

# Crear Label
my_label = Label(root,
    text = "El estatus del botón es ON",
    fg = "green",
    font = ("Helvetica", 32))

my_label.pack(pady = 20)

# Función para el botón
def switch():
    # Usamos la variable global para saber el estado actual del botón
    global is_on
    
    # Determina si el botón está encendido o apagado
    if is_on:
        on_button.config(text = off)
        my_label.config(text = "El estatus del botón es OFF",
                        fg = "red")
        is_on = False
    else:
        on_button.config(text = on)
        my_label.config(text = "El estatus del botón es ON", fg = "green")
        is_on = True

# Definir texto del botón
on = 'Botón ON'
off = 'Botón OFF'


on_button = Button(root, text=on, bd = 2,
                command = switch)
on_button.pack(pady = 50)
root.mainloop()
```